# ast - Get the list of only the variable names in an expression

Tags: python, python-ast

I'm using the Python ast module to obtain a list of variable names in a Python expression. For example, the expression `[int(s[i:i + 3], 2) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]` should return a singleton list with the variable name s like `[s]`. I've tried the following code snippet -

```
names = [
    node.id for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(formula)) 
    if isinstance(node, ast.Name)
]
```

which returns a list of variables plus function names in the ast -

```
['int', 'i', 's', 'range', 'i', 'len', 's', 'i']
```

But I don't want to include function names like `range`, `len`, `int` and the iterator `i`.

Comment: How would the AST know whether a variable points to a function or not? Do you want to exclude the nodes that are part of a call? Why don't you consider ``i`` to be a variable? Are you specifically looking for free/unbound names, i.e. those looked up from outside the expression?

Comment: All the `identifiers` are just variable names to the syntactic parser. E.g. `int`, `isinstance` or `range` can just as easily be bound to objects other that the built-ins they ususally refer to. You would have to gather extra information from the `locals` and `globals` context in which the formula would be evaluated.

Comment: Yes I want to exclude nodes part of a call and those generated during iteration.

Comment: What about nodes in assignment expressions? What about parameters of ``lambda``s?

Comment: In the expression `sum(map(lambda x: x * x, l))`, I want to include `l` but not include `x`. In case of assignment expressions, exclude the lhs node.

Answer (score -1):

You can use similar approach but then filter out names from builtins. Something like this

```
import ast
import builtins

def get_variables(expression):
    tree = ast.parse(expression)
    variables = []
    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Name):
            variables.append(node.id)
    return tuple(v for v in set(variables) if v not in vars(builtins))
```

Comment: This won't filter out the loop-local variable `i` in the example.